# Does devise make sense for a Rails-based web service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

For those with experience, I'm looking to build some web services with Rails. These services will not served HTML content to a web browser and work strictly with XML and JSON only. Since Devise is a full blown MVC module, does it make sense for me? I need solid authentication with custom routes and access to Facebook Connect (OmniAuth looks good for this). I just don't need all of the additional work it's doing in views/layouts.

Is it still a good idea to try it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, devise is worth it because it also handles all of the authentication you still need. The view-helpers are just one (very small) part of that functionality.